Test class to cover 75% code coverage , getting fatal error for the codes
Test coverage for the below Apex classes are not enough, getting errors while deployment.
public class AccountDiscountsController {
public Account accountRec { get; set; }
public String accId { get; set; }
public List accountDiscounts { get; set; }
public Map<String, List> groupedData { get; set; }
public AccountDiscountsController() {
    accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rid');
}

public AccountDiscountsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    accId = 'asd';
    accountRec = (Account)controller.getRecord();
    accountDiscounts = new List<AccountDiscountWrapper>();

    List<Product_Discount__c> productDiscounts = [
        SELECT Id, Name, Product_type__c,  Discount_Request__c, Discount_Request__r.Name,
               Product_group__c, Discount__c, Product_Discount3__c
        FROM Product_Discount__c
        WHERE Discount_Request__r.Account__c = :accountRec.Id
        ORDER BY Product_type__c, Product_group__c, Product_Discount3__c
    ];

    List<Discount_Request__c> discountRequests = [
        SELECT Name
        FROM Discount_Request__c
        WHERE Account__c = :accountRec.Id
    ];

    Map<Id, Date> productDiscountApprovalDateById = new Map<Id, Date>();

    for (ProcessInstance approval : [
        SELECT Id, Status, TargetObjectId, CreatedDate
        FROM ProcessInstance
        WHERE TargetObjectId IN :discountRequests AND Status = 'Approved'
        ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
    ]) {
        productDiscountApprovalDateById.put(approval.TargetObjectId, approval.CreatedDate.date());
    }

    groupedData = new Map<String, List<AccountDiscountWrapper>>();

    for (Product_Discount__c productDiscount : productDiscounts) {
        AccountDiscountWrapper wrapper = new AccountDiscountWrapper();
        wrapper.Approval_Discount_req_Date_c = productDiscountApprovalDateById.get(productDiscount.Discount_Request__c);
        wrapper.Discount_Request_No_c = productDiscount.Discount_Request__r.Name;
        wrapper.Product_Discount_Name_c = productDiscount.Name;
        wrapper.Blum_Consum_Access_c = productDiscount.Product_type__c;
        wrapper.Product_Segment_c = productDiscount.Product_group__c;
        wrapper.Product_Group_Discount_c = productDiscount.Discount__c;
        wrapper.Discount_c = productDiscount.Product_Discount3__c;

        String key = wrapper.Blum_Consum_Access_c + wrapper.Product_Segment_c + wrapper.Product_Group_Discount_c;

        if (!groupedData.containsKey(key)) {
            groupedData.put(key, new List<AccountDiscountWrapper>());
        }

        groupedData.get(key).add(wrapper);
    }

    processData();
}

public void sortAccountDiscounts() {
    accountDiscounts.sort(new AccountDiscountWrapperComparator());
}

public void processData() {
    accountDiscounts = new List<AccountDiscountWrapper>();

    for (String key : groupedData.keySet()) {
        List<AccountDiscountWrapper> groupDiscounts = groupedData.get(key);

        // Sort groupDiscounts based on Product_Type__c, Product_Group__c, and Product_Group_Discount_c
        groupDiscounts.sort(new AccountDiscountWrapperComparator());

        AccountDiscountWrapper latestDiscount = groupDiscounts[0];

        if (isProductGroupBlank(latestDiscount)) {
            latestDiscount.Product_Group_Discount_c = '';
        }

        accountDiscounts.add(latestDiscount);
    }

    sortAccountDiscounts();
}

private Boolean isProductGroupBlank(AccountDiscountWrapper discount) {
    List<String> blankProductSegments = new List<String>{'ALL-Blum', 'ALL-Consumables', 'ALL Blum Hinges'};
    return blankProductSegments.contains(discount.Product_Segment_c);
}

public class AccountDiscountWrapper {
    public Date Approval_Discount_req_Date_c { get; set; }
    public String Discount_Request_No_c { get; set; }
    public String Product_Discount_Name_c { get; set; }
    public String Blum_Consum_Access_c { get; set; }
    public String Product_Segment_c { get; set; }
    public String Product_Group_Discount_c { get; set; }
    public String Discount_c { get; set; }
}

public class AccountDiscountWrapperComparator implements Comparator<AccountDiscountWrapper> {
    public Integer compare(AccountDiscountWrapper a, AccountDiscountWrapper b) {
        // Compare Product_Type__c
        Integer typeComparison = a.Blum_Consum_Access_c.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.Blum_Consum_Access_c.toLowerCase());
        if (typeComparison != 0) {
            return typeComparison;
        }
        
        // Compare Product_Group__c if Product_Type__c is the same
        Integer groupComparison = a.Product_Segment_c.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.Product_Segment_c.toLowerCase());
        if (groupComparison != 0) {
            return groupComparison;
        }
        
        // Compare Product_Group_Discount_c if Product_Type__c and Product_Group__c are the same
        Integer productGroupComparison = a.Product_Group_Discount_c.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.Product_Group_Discount_c.toLowerCase());
        if (productGroupComparison != 0) {
            return productGroupComparison;
        }

        // Compare other fields if needed
        // For example, compare Discount_Request_No_c or Approval_Discount_req_Date_c

        return 0;
    }
}

}
Test:
@isTest
public class AccountDiscountsControllerTest {
// Utility method to create test data
private static void createTestData() {
    // Create test Account
    Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
    insert testAccount;

    // Create test Discount_Request__c
    Discount_Request__c discountRequest = new Discount_Request__c(
        Account__c = testAccount.Id
    );
    insert discountRequest;

    // Create test Product_Discount__c records
    Product_Discount__c productDiscount1 = new Product_Discount__c(
        Name = 'Discount 1',
        Product_type__c = 'Type1',
        Discount_Request__c = discountRequest.Id,
        Product_group__c = 'Group1',
        Discount__c = '10%',
        Product_Discount3__c = '5%'
    );
    insert productDiscount1;

    Product_Discount__c productDiscount2 = new Product_Discount__c(
        Name = 'Discount 2',
        Product_type__c = 'Type2',
        Discount_Request__c = discountRequest.Id,
        Product_group__c = 'Group2',
        Discount__c = '15%',
        Product_Discount3__c = '7%'
    );
    insert productDiscount2;

    // Create test ProcessInstance
    ProcessInstance processInstance = new ProcessInstance(
        Status = 'Approved',
        TargetObjectId = discountRequest.Id
    );
    insert processInstance;
}

@isTest
static void testAccountDiscountsControllerDefaultConstructor() {
   // Test.startTest();

    // Set page parameters
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('rid', '001000000000000');

    // Instantiate the controller
    AccountDiscountsController controller = new AccountDiscountsController();

   // Test.stopTest();

    // Verify the controller's properties
    System.assertEquals('001000000000000', controller.accId, 'The accId should match the parameter.');
}

@isTest
static void testAccountDiscountsControllerStandardControllerConstructor() {
    createTestData();

    // Fetch the test account
    Account testAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account' LIMIT 1];

    //Test.startTest();

    // Instantiate the standard controller and custom controller
    ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(testAccount);
    AccountDiscountsController controller = new AccountDiscountsController(stdController);

   // Test.stopTest();

    // Verify the controller's properties
    System.assertEquals(testAccount.Id, controller.accountRec.Id, 'The account record should be set.');
   // System.assertNotNull(controller.accountDiscounts, 'The accountDiscounts list should not be null.');
   // System.assertNotNull(controller.groupedData, 'The groupedData map should not be null.');
}

@isTest
static void testSortAccountDiscounts() {
    createTestData();

    // Fetch the test account
    Account testAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account' LIMIT 1];

    //Test.startTest();

    // Instantiate the standard controller and custom controller
    ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(testAccount);
    AccountDiscountsController controller = new AccountDiscountsController(stdController);

    // Call the sortAccountDiscounts method
    controller.sortAccountDiscounts();

    //Test.stopTest();

    // Verify the sorted order of the account discounts
    System.assert(controller.accountDiscounts.size() > 0, 'The accountDiscounts list should contain elements.');
}

@isTest
static void testProcessData() {
    createTestData();

    // Fetch the test account
    Account testAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account' LIMIT 1];

   // Test.startTest();

    // Instantiate the standard controller and custom controller
    ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(testAccount);
    AccountDiscountsController controller = new AccountDiscountsController(stdController);

    // Call the processData method
    controller.processData();

    //Test.stopTest();

    // Verify the processed data
    System.assert(controller.accountDiscounts.size() > 0, 'The accountDiscounts list should contain elements.');
}

@isTest
static void testIsProductGroupBlank() {
    AccountDiscountsController controller = new AccountDiscountsController();

    AccountDiscountsController.AccountDiscountWrapper wrapper = new AccountDiscountsController.AccountDiscountWrapper();
    wrapper.Product_Segment_c = 'ALL-Blum';

   // Boolean result = controller.isProductGroupBlank(wrapper);

   // System.assert(result, 'The result should be true for blank product groups.');
}

}
class
public with sharing class ProductController {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Product_discount__c> productDiscounts(String recordId) {
try {
List<Product_discount__c> pro = [SELECT Id, Name, Discount__c, Product_group__c, Product_type__c, Product_Discount3__c FROM Product_discount__c WHERE Discount_Request__c = :recordId];
return pro;
} catch (Exception e) {
// Handle exceptions appropriately, e.g., logging or rethrowing a custom exception
throw e;
}
}
@AuraEnabled
public static void deleteLineItems(String deleteId) {
    try {
        List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
        for (String idString : deleteId.split(',')) {
            ids.add(idString);
        }
        List<Product_discount__c> discountList = [SELECT Id FROM Product_discount__c WHERE Id IN :ids];
        delete discountList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle exceptions appropriately, e.g., logging or rethrowing a custom exception
        throw e;
    }
}

@AuraEnabled
public static void createProductDiscount(
    String name,
    String productType,
    String productGroup,
    String discount,
    String discountRequest
) {
    try {
        Product_discount__c newDiscount = new Product_discount__c();
        newDiscount.Name = name;
        newDiscount.Product_type__c = productType;
        newDiscount.Product_group__c = productGroup;
        newDiscount.Discount__c = discount;
        newDiscount.Discount_Request__c = discountRequest;

        insert newDiscount;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle exceptions appropriately, e.g., logging or rethrowing a custom exception
        throw e;
    }
}

}
Test class
@isTest
public class ProductControllerTest {
@testSetup
static void setup() {
// Create test Account
Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
insert testAccount;
    // Create test Discount_Request__c
    Discount_Request__c discountRequest = new Discount_Request__c(Account__c = testAccount.Id);
    insert discountRequest;
    
    // Create test Product_discount__c records
    Product_discount__c productDiscount1 = new Product_discount__c(
        Name = 'Discount 1',
        Product_type__c = 'Type1',
        Product_group__c = 'Group1',
        Discount__c = '10%',
        Product_Discount3__c = '5%',
        Discount_Request__c = discountRequest.Id
    );
    insert productDiscount1;

    Product_discount__c productDiscount2 = new Product_discount__c(
        Name = 'Discount 2',
        Product_type__c = 'Type2',
        Product_group__c = 'Group2',
        Discount__c = '15%',
        Product_Discount3__c = '7%',
        Discount_Request__c = discountRequest.Id
    );
    insert productDiscount2;
}

@isTest
static void testProductDiscounts() {
    // Fetch the test Discount_Request__c
    Discount_Request__c discountRequest = [SELECT Id FROM Discount_Request__c LIMIT 1];
    
   // Test.startTest();
    
    // Call the method
    List<Product_discount__c> discounts = ProductController.productDiscounts(discountRequest.Id);
    
   // Test.stopTest();
    
    // Verify the results
    System.assertNotEquals(0, discounts.size(), 'Discounts should be returned.');
    System.assertEquals('Discount 1', discounts[0].Name, 'First discount name should match.');
    System.assertEquals('Discount 2', discounts[1].Name, 'Second discount name should match.');
}

@isTest
static void testDeleteLineItems() {
    // Fetch the test Product_discount__c records
    List<Product_discount__c> productDiscounts = [SELECT Id FROM Product_discount__c];
    
    String deleteId = productDiscounts[0].Id + ',' + productDiscounts[1].Id;
    
   // Test.startTest();
    
    // Call the method
    ProductController.deleteLineItems(deleteId);
    
    //Test.stopTest();
    
    // Verify the records were deleted
    List<Product_discount__c> deletedDiscounts = [SELECT Id FROM Product_discount__c WHERE Id IN :productDiscounts];
    System.assertEquals(0, deletedDiscounts.size(), 'All discounts should be deleted.');
}

@isTest
static void testCreateProductDiscount() {
    // Fetch the test Discount_Request__c
    Discount_Request__c discountRequest = [SELECT Id FROM Discount_Request__c LIMIT 1];
    
   // Test.startTest();
    
    // Call the method
    ProductController.createProductDiscount('New Discount', 'Type3', 'Group3', '20%', discountRequest.Id);
    
   // Test.stopTest();
    
    // Verify the new discount was created
    Product_discount__c newDiscount = [SELECT Name, Product_type__c, Product_group__c, Discount__c, Discount_Request__c FROM Product_discount__c WHERE Name = 'New Discount' LIMIT 1];
    System.assertEquals('New Discount', newDiscount.Name, 'Discount name should match.');
    System.assertEquals('Type3', newDiscount.Product_type__c, 'Product type should match.');
    System.assertEquals('Group3', newDiscount.Product_group__c, 'Product group should match.');
    System.assertEquals('20%', newDiscount.Discount__c, 'Discount should match.');
    System.assertEquals(discountRequest.Id, newDiscount.Discount_Request__c, 'Discount request should match.');
}

}
